# Custom C# DLL, error 429 from VBA

Tags: c#, excel, dll

Have serious trouble with calling a simple C# DLL from VBA, can't get it to work. Tried several things that appeared to work for others, but no luck.

Machine 1: Windows 7, Visual Sudio 2013 Express, Office 2010

Here is my C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DLLTester3
{
    [Guid("6A40F90B-B8FC-4F4A-9B4C-850279D45B3B")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("DLLTester3.DoSometing")]
    public class DLLTester3
    {
        public void DoSometing()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Have "Make assembly COM-visible" and "Register form COM interop" set to true, signed the assembly.

Running the following VBA from Excel works as expected:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DoIt()
    Dim Something As DLLTester3.DLLTester3
    Set Something = New DLLTester3.DLLTester3
    Call Something.DoSometing
End Sub
```

Machine 2: Windows 10, Office 2013
Machine 3: Windows Server 2008, Office 2010
Copied the DLL, registered it using REGASM with `/codebase` option, both machines give error 429.

Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Regasm.exe problem, probably.  Given that you have 4 versions to choose from, the odds that you'll pick the wrong one are about 75%.  Well, 100% at SO.  Be explicit about which one you used.

Comment: Target Framework 4.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe (on Win 10)

Comment: Given the 100% odds, use the one in the Framework directory instead.  The one in Framwork64 only works for 64-bit processes and Office is still very commonly a 32-bit install.

Comment: Hans, great! that last one did the trick on the Win10 machine!

Win Server probable needs more software as I cannot find GACUTIL there

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have done:

- you have added ProgId
- you have added GUID
- you have sigend the dll
- COM visible

You need to do:

1. use the right version of gacutil to add your dll to GAC

   C:\VBS\DNFW4\gacutil.exe /i XXX.dll
2. use the right version of RegAsm to reg the dll

   C:\VBS\DNFW4\RegAsm.exe XXX.dll

now you can use vbs to test it:

```
On Error Resume Next

Err.Clear

Set Obj=CreateObject("ProgId")

'output the error msg
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Number
    WScript.Echo "Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number)
    WScript.Echo "Source: " &  Err.Source
    WScript.Echo "Description: " &  Err.Description
    'Err.Clear
    'Quit
    WScript.Quit(Err.Number)
End If

'On Error Goto 0

'invoke the add method
WScript.Echo obj.Add(1,2)


set obj=Nothin
```

Comment: @AntonK Can you invoke your  COM by VBS? If so, will you try Framework3.5 instead Framework4 ? VBA supports  Framework3.5 and  Framework2.0 better.